# tomcat is not accessible when it runs in port 8080

Tags: tomcat, fedora

I running a tomcat server on port 8080  in my Fedora 14 box. I am able to get the web pages from that same machine. But when I try to access it from my windows machine which is another network , the web browser is getting timed out.

If I run the same tomcat in port 80 , its accessible from my windows machine . 
Note : from my windows machine , am able to do 'ping'  the Fedora box.
Does anyone know the reason for this ?

Comment: are you typing in the right URL to get to the web page when tomcat is running on 8080 (ie.  are you entering thisisyouripaddressorhostname:8080 )?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely to be a firewall either on the Linux box, the Windows box or in between - what happens if you just telnet 8080 it? Try just disabling the Windows firewall as that's usually a very quick and easy way to get rid of one potential source of the problem. Then, if you can, disable the firewall on the Linux box at the same time too - if that doesn't work then you may need to talk to your network/security people. It does work ok on the server itself right? you've checked?

Comment: telnet on 8080 is not working. In both the windows and linux machines the firewall is in OFF. I wonder how am able to access from the windows box when the server is running in port 80 and its not in port 8080

Comment: Because it sounds like you have a firewall between the two machines, this is very common by the way- do you know your network/security people, if so go and have a chat with them.

Comment: Could you post your network information. Maybe client/server IP addresses and any network equipment that can be involved (routers).

Answer (score 1):

Some things you can do to get some proof that the problem is in the network:

Double check, that tomcat is listening where it's supposed to:

```
netstat -nat|grep :8080
```

You should see something like:

```
tcp       0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN
```

If not something went wrong with the Tomcat startup. Check catalina.out.

Try to access tomcat locally on the Fedora box:

```
w3m http://localhost:8080/
```

Listen in on the network and see if the requests from your Windows PC get to the server at all. As root on your Fedora box run this:

```
tcpdump port 8080
```

Leave this running while you're trying to access http://fedorabox:8080/ from your Windows PC. If tcpdump doesn't show any traffic, your requests clearly get lost somewhere on the way, which means you do have to talk to your network people.